# How to read the pictures file from a specified uri

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm trying to read, with the cursor, the files specified in the URI from me. But I can not figure out where the error does not seem to read from the path that I have indicated

This is the Code:

```
 public static Uri getRandomImage(ContentResolver resolver) {

    String[] projection = new String[] {
        BaseColumns._ID,

    };


    Uri uri = Media.getContentUri("/sdcard/DCIM/Wallpaper/");

    String[] selectionArgs = null; // there is no ? in selection so null here

    String sortOrder = null; // unordered
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, null, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            return null;
    }

    cursor.moveToPosition(new Random().nextInt(cursor.getCount()));

    return Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, cursor.getString(0));
}
```

this is the code where there is a new error:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;

    try {
        pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r"); //line with error
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(fnfe));
        return null;
    }
```

This is the log cat:

```
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: 
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:464)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:380)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView.getImageFromUri(TileView.java:560)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView.onDraw(TileView.java:239)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6741)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6744)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6744)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6744)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/it.bisemanuDEV.slidepuzzle.TileView(11188):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It seems that the error is now in `getImageFromUri()`. Your should provide the code for this method.

Comment: I posted the piece of code in which there is the error of the method getimagefromUri. I commenting the line specified by the logcat

Answer (score 0):

The class `MediaStore.Files` is only available since API level 11 (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html).

You will get this error if you try to use it on a device with a lower android version.

Comment: I've edited my question using Uri uri = Media.getContentUri("/sdcard/DCIM/Wallpaper/"); and I have a new error. I posted the logcat

Comment: Well you should be probably have posted a new question then, because it seems to be a different problem now

Answer (score 0):

You probably misunderstand the `volumeName` parameter of `getContentUri()` method.

It should be one of "internal" or "external" (see [What does MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(String volumeName):Uri do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947692/what-does-mediastore-images-media-getcontenturistring-volumenameuri-do))

Comment: If I try with the Istruction Uri uri = Media.getContentUri ("external"), the app do not crashes, but the cursor moves on all files present in the gallery instead I would shift only the files contained in "/ sdcard / DCIM / Wallpaper / "